# How to make Paypal button for accepting payments with Node SDK?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Creating a buy now button with the button builder on the paypal website only allows you to create a button that will send the user to the paypal website for checking out with paypal.

I'm using the nodejs SDK to directly accept credit cards and prevent the user from having to leave my website in order to complete the payment.  My question is **how can I create a paypal button that calls the appropriate function in my application when the button is clicked instead of taking the user to a paypal payment page**?

I'm assuming that when the payment button is clicked it ought to trigger a function in my application that creates the payment using the nodejs paypal rest-SDK module instead of sending the user to the paypal website.

The problem is that I could create any old button, but to comply with paypal's developer agreement it seems you have to use their buttons.  The only solution I've thought of is to download one of their button image files from their website. This image could then be used to make a button that calls the appropriate function.  Would this be okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Direct Credit Card integrations, you do not have to use a PayPal button as your customers do not even need to know PayPal is involved. Typically, you would build a form to collect the customer and credit card data then post that to a script on the back end to map those variables to the correct SDK fields and submit the payment.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was hoping someone would say.  The only thing is that I was under the impression that abiding by Paypal "branding" policy, developers need to use paypal buttons.  This means I'll at least need to download one of their button images from their website and use that as my button right?  Then I can attach a function to that button which will make a post request to the backend.

Comment: Also, is the process you mentioned secure?  Will I need to encrypt the form information or something like that?

Comment: The ideal situation is that you would also include a method for PayPal customers to check out, usually using PayPal Express Checkout. So, you would have an option for Credit Card where no PayPal branding is necessary, and then an option for PayPal.

Comment: As for being secure, you will need to research PCI compliance and be sure you are meeting the requirements for security through them as you are dealing with credit card information. Typically this means your site should be SSL secured and you encrypt the credit card data before sending to PayPal servers.

Comment: If I encrypt the card data before I send it to the paypal servers how can the servers decrypt the information after they receive it?

Comment: It would be encrypted by your SSL certificate, so would be decrypted like any other SSL-secured communication.